# CSS3/jQuery selector to style group of 2 rows via the :nt-child() selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, css

I have a `<table>` that the data is separated per 2 `<tr>`'s

So i want to style the rows(each 2 rows) as zebra stripped, but each set of 2 should be styled.

I am trying something like:

```
 tr:nth-child(3n+1), tr:nth-child(4n+1){background:#f7f7f7;}
```

I would prefer a CSS3 solution, but if only jQuery can do it, that will be fine.

Please see [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/M38Bb/) (editable via jsFiddle):

I tried to play around with css-tricks [nth-child-tester](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/), but i couldn't get it.

#### The question is how do i zebra style each set of (2) TR's (rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/D8eT9/) is a fork where every pair of rows is styled.

I had to edit the colour to see anything.

You need to use (4n+1) and (4n+2).

Comment: Thanks, how do i have it start from the second group?
now the first 2 are black and skips 2.  how do i have it start from 1-2 none, 3-4 black, 5-6 none, 7-8 black.... ?

Comment: Thanks much, Like the idea that you forked the original.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
tbody tr:nth-child(4n+1){background:#f00;}
tbody tr:nth-child(4n+2){background:#f00;}
tbody tr:nth-child(4n+3){background:#0f0;}
tbody tr:nth-child(4n+4){background:#0f0;}
```

This will color pairs of rows alternating as red and green.

Comment: Thanks much, yes this works, but i would have to do it explicitly for each set.

Answer (score 1):

Either of these would work:

```
tr:nth-child(4n+1), tr:nth-child(4n+1)+tr {  }
tr:nth-child(4n+1), tr:nth-child(4n+2) {  }
```

Comment: Yea, i like the firs solution, its pretty neat. and it has the least char's. Thanks much.